# Windows 10 PowerShell cannot add network locations past \\xxx\xxx

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, network-drive

I have been trying to create a network drive using PowerShell that has a network location nested further than `\\xxx\xxx`, but I am unable to do so; whenever I try, I get error: 
 <sup>(parts in brackets are edited for privacy)</sup>

```powershell
"New-PsDrive -Name "z" -PsProvider "filesystem" -Root "\\{domain-name}.sharepoint.com@SSL\personal\{my-username}\Documents" -Persist"

  New-PsDrive : The network resource type is not correct
    At line:1 char:1
    + New-PsDrive -Name "z" -PsProvider "filesystem" -Root "\\{domain-name}\..."
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (z:PSDriveInfo) [New-PSDrive], Win32Exception
      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CouldNotMapNetworkDrive,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewPSDriveCommand
```

- I am running this through a `.bat` file, which functions fine, as I cannot use `.ps1` scripts due to the execution policy I can't change; there is an `.exe` file that creates this path, so I know it is possible, but using it is very inconvenient

To answer questions:

Yes, I have checked the docs, and cannot see a way of making this work, it may be that I have not interpreted the code correctly, but I don't think that is likely the answer.

I have tried the code suggested by user19702, but it had not worked, I also opened PowerShell at the network location, and it worked fine, with no complaints, I have tried all the logins I have twice and could not get the drive to be added.

Is there any way I can fix this error and create the network location?

Comment: _(Please don't cut off error output of the command used, as while it may not be important in this instance, it helps others verify the executed syntax was correct)_ I don't have the time at the moment to determine if this offers any insight, but have you reviewed [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-psdrive)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30298850/powershell-map-persistent-sharepoint-path

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that you are using the correct credentials for your sharepoint - my powershell gives the same error unless you provide a `-Credential` flag, even though I'm using the same account:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Z -PSProvider FileSystem -Root '\\sharepoint.domain.com@SSL\path\to\folder\' -Credential (get-credential) -persist
```

Try and browse to the folder in windows explorer, then do shift+right-click > open powershell window here, and see if it complains about anything else there too

And since you're using batch to launch powershell, be careful of [special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6828751/batch-character-escaping) in your url or elsewhere: `%` `^` `&` `<` `>` `|`